# Git: receive.denyCurrentBranch=updateInstead does not update

Tags: git

The `receive.denyCurrentBranch=updateInstead` option (set on the server repo), according to the docs, should allow the push and do a hard reset of the worktree if it's clean, or just refuse the push if the worktree isn't clean.

Instead, for me it allows the push, but doesn't update the worktree - I have to `git checkout -f` after each push anyway, even though it's cleanish (has just untracked files present, which, if I'm not mistaken, should still count as clean).

Edit: (resolved since) The `push-to-checkout` hook doesn't seem to run, either, even though it's in the .git/hooks/push-to-checkout file all right, with +x rights as needed. I made it output some lines and exit with code 1, so it should abort after producing the output - and yet the pushes come through. The "update" hook works, so hooks are not all dead.

Edit 2: Hooks started working, further complicating the issue. How is push-to-checkout firing, but the worktree isn't getting updated to match the index?

My client is 2.31.0.windows.1 (TortoiseGit), server is 2.39.1 if that one matters. I connect via SSH.

Comment: Do you have that option set on the client where you're pushing or on the server where the push is being received?  It needs to be set on the server.

Comment: Definitely on the server. My .git/config contains:
[receive]
denyCurrentBranch = updateInstead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Git's documentation is a little misleading on this one.

> This hook is to be used to override the default behaviour.

This actually means that if the `push-to-checkout` hook is in place, it needs to ENTIRELY REIMPLEMENT the worktree update routine! It's not like all the other hooks, which can do whatever they like as long as they return zero exit values.

So, for a proper push-to-checkout behaviour, simply DO NOT USE A HOOK unless you implement the worktree update inside it.